# What is the length of a parabola between $-1$ and $1$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

In other terms, what is the value of $$2\sum _{n=1}^{\left(x\right)}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\left(x\right)^2+\left(2n-1\right)^2}}{\left(x\right)^2}\right)$$ as $x\to \infty$?

I have $2.95784430626$ as a limited decimal, but it's not what I want

Also what is the simplified version of this graph?: $$y=\sum _{n=1}^s\left(\sqrt{\left(\left(\frac{n}{s}-x\right)-\left(\frac{\left(n-1\right)}{s}-x\right)\right)^2+\left(\left(\left(\frac{n}{s}-x\right)^2\right)-\left(\frac{\left(n-1\right)}{s}-x\right)^2\right)^2}\right)$$ as $s\to \infty$

In other words, that's $$\int_{1}^{-1}dx\sqrt{1+\frac{dy}{dx}^2}$$

Comment: Write $ instead of [;

Comment: Your answer is equivalent to $\sqrt{5}+\frac 12\ln(2+\sqrt{5})$

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will help answer the question, but I thought I would give it a try.  So, let's have a look at the Riemann sum for the integral

$$2\int_0^1\sqrt{1+4t^2}\,dt=\sqrt{5}+\frac12 \text{arcsinh}(2)$$

First, partition the interval $[0,1]$ into equal $x$ subintervals of length $1/x.\,\,$  Notice that the midpoint of interval $n$ is $t_n=\frac{2n-1}{2x}$.

Then, using the mid-point evaluation in the Riemann sum gives

$$\begin{align}
2\int_0^1\sqrt{1+4t^2}\,dt&=\lim_{x \to \infty}2\sum_{n=1}^x \sqrt{1+4t_n^2}\,\left(\frac1x\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty}2\sum_{n=1}^x \sqrt{1+4\left(\frac{2n-1}{2x}\right)^2}\,\left(\frac1x\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty}2\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{\sqrt{x^2+\left(2n-1\right)^2}}{x^2}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.